# About ISBN Checksum Bit

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have question about ISBN 10-digit checksum bit. I know the formula for calculating checksum bit is 
$$a_{10} \equiv 0\cdot a_0 + 1\cdot a_1 + 2\cdot a_2 + \ldots 9\cdot a_9\pmod{11}$$
I have this ISBN 0-07-232569-0, once I use this formulate for this I have a total sum of $186 \pmod{11} = 10$. I understand if this ISBN is correct it must be $0$ but I checked this ISBN on the internet it says this ISBN is correct , could someone help me ?

Comment: Your formula is wrong, the first coefficient is $1$, not $0$.  All subsequent coefficients are also off by one.  The formula in the question is somewhat useless as a checksum since it is unable to detect any error in the digit $a_0$.

Comment: Thanks Erick everything is more meaninful now thanks to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the digits are "abcdefghi-j" where j is the check digit. Then the check digit is computed by the following formula: 
j = ( [a b c d e f g h i] * [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9] ) mod 11 which in this case is zero. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your helps i understand know exactly